# Security proof in (Ciphertext-Policy) Attribute-Based Encryption

Tags: encryption, provable-security, protocol-analysis, abe

I am having hard time understanding the security proof in Attribute-Based Encryption, especially in Ciphertext-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption.

To do reduction in CP-ABE scheme, how do I check that the security proof is correct or works. For example, there is a CP-ABE scheme in section 3 of [Ciphertext-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption: An Expressive, Efficient, and Provably Secure Realization](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/290.pdf). How can I approach the paper and check whether the security proof of the scheme is correct?